# How to check if the timezone data used by the JavaScript Internationalization API (Intl) has changed?

Tags: timezone, internationalization, dayjs

I am using `Day.js` to handle timezone related operations. `Day.js` relies on the JavaScript Internationalization API (Intl) to get timezone data.

To my understanding, the Internationalization API relies on the underlying system/browser to provide timezone information.

My question is, how would I check if the timezone data used by the Internationalization API has been updated?

**Why do I care about this?**
I store *future* `dateTimes` with 3 values:

1. local `dateTime` (local to the associated timezone)
2. utc `dateTime`
3. timezone

When there is a change in this timezone data, it might happen that the offset between the "local" and "utc" `dateTimes` is no longer correct. When this happens I would like to know about it, so that I can calculate and store the new utc `dateTime`, such that the offset is now correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for `Node.js` environments (not sure about browser environments though).

In `Node.js` you can find a list of all of the versions of its dependencies on `process.versions` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processversion)). One of these is the `tz` dependency, which corresponds to the version of the timezone data used ([the IANA version](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)).

In order to check if the version has changed, I store the version in the db and simply compare.